# android string datetime format with month and day

Tags: android, datetime, datetime-format

i have like this datetime 09/01/2014 and i want to  format this datetime like this 1 september. i wrote some code and i can  format this date like this

```
                        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

                        Date _d = df.parse("09/01/2014");                   
                        SimpleDateFormat new_df = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "dd");
                        String _s = new_df.format(_d);
                        cinemaTime.setStartTime(_s);
```

in this code result is onlu  01 but i don't know how i can recive 1 september(9th month of years(
if anyone knows solution please help me thanks

Comment: whats is exactly the format that you want to receive?  "1 september(9th month of years(" ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this method will do the job if you want an output like "1 september 2014".

```
public static String dateFormatterforLukka(){       
    String inputDate = "09/01/2014";        
    String inputFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    String outputFormat = "d ' ' MMMM ' ' yyyy";

    Date parsed = null;
    String outputDate = "";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df_input = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, new Locale("en", "US"));
        SimpleDateFormat df_output = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, new Locale("en", "US"));                    
        parsed = df_input.parse(inputDate);
        outputDate = df_output.format(parsed);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        outputDate = inputDate;     
    }
    return outputDate;
}
```

Read the documentation about:  **[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Class**

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting "01" because that's all you asked it to give you (`"dd"`). `MMMM` will give you the month as a word. If you want just "1" instead of "01", you would just use `d` instead of `dd`.

Further documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: problem solved .this is a solution  SimpleDateFormat new_df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM"); thanks.but it is a possible to change language?

Comment: You should be able to add a `Locale` with `new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM", Locale.FRENCH);`

Comment: Documentation for locale: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#field_summary